# Selecting item in whitelist in yairEO/tagify

Tags: tagify

I'm trying to understand why suggestions in dropdown doesn't shows after the first tag is added.

Try to look at this example
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-einstein-yew7ni?file=/src/index.js

I noticed also the click on the suggested item will not automatically add them in the tags list.

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-einstein-yew7ni?file=/src/index.js

I think the problem is related to renaming the value property